# How to heat empty directory in WiX?

Tags: wix

Here's the cakebuild script:

```
  WiXHeat(Directory("../Release"), new FilePath("./xxx/Files.wxs"), WiXHarvestType.Dir, new HeatSettings
  {
    AutogeneratedGuid = true,
    ComponentGroupName = "Binaries",
    Transform = "./Filter.xslt",
    SuppressCom = true,
    SuppressFragments = true,
    SuppressRegistry = true,
    SuppressRootDirectory = true,
    PreprocessorVariable = "var.xxx.TargetDir",
    DirectoryReferenceId = "INSTALLFOLDER",
    WorkingDirectory = "./xxx_Installer",
    KeepEmptyDirectories = true,
    GenerateGuid = true,
  });
```

It uses arguments: -ke -ag -gg.

The Files.wxs looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Directory Id="dir76A8B56EDC1C4DD3CB4177F3704BC91E" Name="data">
                <Component Id="cmpE375532277DA492834892BE47B02E5DA" Guid="*" KeyPath="yes">
                    <CreateFolder />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="Binaries">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpE375532277DA492834892BE47B02E5DA" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Then Light doesn't work with Files.wxs, here's the error:

> ...\Files.wxs(29) : error LGHT0230 : The Component/@Guid attribute's
>   value  '*' is not valid for this component because it does not meet
>   the criteria for having an automatically generated guid. Components
>   using a Directory as  a KeyPath or containing ODBCDataSource child
>   elements cannot use an automatically generated guid. Make sure your
>   component doesn't have a Directory a s the KeyPath and move any
>   ODBCDataSource child elements to components with explicit component
>   guids. An error occured when executing task 'BuildInstaller'. Error:
>   Light: Process returned an error (exit code 230).

Seems that for empty directory, it must have an assigned guild, not "*" according to [this article](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Heat-ke-error-empty-directories-td7586127.html).

I don't want to manually replace "*" with a GUID, since the heat/light process is integrated with build process and Files.wxs is in source control.

Do you know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

You use the heat parameters -ag and -gg at the same time.

Either I missed something or

> **-ag** - Auto generate component guids at compile time, e.g. set Guid="*".
>
> **-gg** - Generate guids now. All components are given a guid when heat is run.
>
> source http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html

can not be met simultaneously.

And because your light fails afterwards during GUID generation I suggest to try out only **-gg** without **-ag**. That just helped me with empty directories too.

Answer (score 1):

I added this snippet, and WiX Light works fine.

```
  <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='data']/wix:Component/@Guid">
    <xsl:attribute name="Guid">
      <xsl:value-of select="'E8A26678-FA90-4BFC-846F-4E79AE55D44D'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

Please comment if this is the right solution.